# Rename matching files based on a serial number

Tags: bash, find, rename

Assuming I have a bunch of files that are mac screenshots:

```
Screen Shot 2018-11-09 at 12.37.37 PM.png
Screen Shot 2018-11-10 at 4.53.02 PM.png
Screen Shot 2018-11-10 at 9.19.19 PM.png
```

And I want to use mv to label them to:

```
Screen_0.png
Screen_1.png
Screen_2.png
```

The partial command I come up with:

```
find . -name "Screen*" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "Screen_$2"' _ {} ??? \;
```

How to implement the command so that it can label image by digits? or do I have to resort to a more complicated file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to pass a sequence number `xargs` in the way you want.  Use a simple loop instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in Screen*.png; do
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue # skip if not a regular file
  mv "$file" "Screen_$((count++)).png"
done
```

Comment: Does `$((count++))` initiate the variable `count` as well? Looks like it. I never knew that's possible.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Please note the post increment - the initial value will be zero.  If you want the initial value to be 1, use `$((++count))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `rename`, a.k.a. Perl rename:

```
rename --dry-run 's/.*/Screen_$N.png/' Screenshot*png
```

**Sample Output**

```
'Screenshot 2018-11-12 at 11.54.32.png' would be renamed to 'Screen_1.png'
'Screenshot 2018-11-12 at 11.54.38.png' would be renamed to 'Screen_2.png'
'Screenshot 2018-11-12 at 11.54.42.png' would be renamed to 'Screen_3.png'
```

If you like the look of the output, run again without `--dry-run`.

---

If you are on macOS, you can install Perl `rename` with **homebrew**:

```
brew install rename
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use an array, no arithmetics is needed, just use the index of each element:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=('Screen Shot'*.png)
for i in "${!files[@]}" ; do
    mv "${files[i]}" Screen_$i.png
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to condense your code into a single line: `files=(Screen*); for i in ${!files[@]}; do mv ${files[i]} "Screen_$i.png"; done` that works in the terminal, much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Perl one liner also, you could do it easily.

```
> ls -1 Screen*
Screen Shot 2018-11-09 at 12.37.37 PM.png
Screen Shot 2018-11-10 at 4.53.02 PM.png
Screen Shot 2018-11-10 at 9.19.19 PM.png
> perl -ne ' BEGIN { for(glob("Screen*")) {  rename "$_", "Screen_".$x++.".png" } ; exit }'
> ls -1 Screen*
Screen_0.png
Screen_1.png
Screen_2.png
>
```