# Bulk rename image files but keep extension same linux

Tags: bash, rename

OS - Ubuntu 16.04

I have 700+ images in a folder of various formats (.jpg .jpeg .png etc). I would like to rename them by the number of that image 
eg - 
Say I have 3 images

```
S.jpg
K.jpg
C.jpg
```

I would like to have their names as

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

Please note that all files are NOT .jpg

I looked up the following article but it was of no help as I have no experience with shell - https://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: This should help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261754/2836621

Comment: for some reason SO was recognizing the image names as code so I put them as code

Comment: @Cyrus I looked it up on duckduckGo and got this result https://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/ but it involved writing Perl scripts and I have never studied perl so I came here for some help. The command always requires writing Perl script so I did not mention my research. Will do next time sorry

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the link to the Q/A. Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea as to how to edit the script to my needs as I have done extremely little shell programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as this should do the trick:

```
i=0; for f in *.*; do mv -- "$f" "$((++i)).${f##*.}"; done
```

If you need to specify the extensions, use: `for f in *.jpg *.png ...`

Answer (score -2):

```
$ ls
C.jpg   K.jpg   S.jpg   w.png   x.jpeg
$ i=0 ; for file in $(find . \( -name "*.png" -or -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.jpeg" \) ) ; do let i++ ;   mv -v $file  $i."${file##*.}" ; done
./C.jpg -> 1.jpg
./K.jpg -> 2.jpg
./S.jpg -> 3.jpg
./w.png -> 4.png
./x.jpeg -> 5.jpeg
```

Comment: no my friend that was just an example. as i mentioned I have 700+ images of various formats(.jpg .jpeg .png etc)

Comment: Updated the answer to support whatever extension the file has.