# Rename multiple files with different names to same name and different numbers

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I have multiple pictures of trucks with random messy names and different formats (jpeg, jpg, png etc.) and I want to rename them to "truck1.jpeg", "truck2.jpg", "truck3.png" and so on. How do I do it using the `rename` command?

Comment: As you need to increment the number, you will need a loop of some kind. However, your description is incomplete. I guess you do *not* want to rename `foo.png` to `truck3.jpg` (changing the extension), I also guess that you want to keep the extension as-is, and I also guess that you are OK with using only one counter (instead of a separate counter for each distinct extension). Am I correct?

Comment: It kinda depends on what the `"random messy names"` are to begin with -- we can't guess what they may be. (and be aware there are 2 different `rename` utilities for LInux with different options, which do you have?)

Comment: @DevSolar Yes, you guessed everything right! Sorry for incomplete question, I'll edit it.

Comment: You could also consider using mmv(1).

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261754/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easier to use `bash` and `mv`, since AFAIK you need something like `bash` to generate the number sequence. In `bash`

```
i=1
for x in *; do 
  echo $x '->' truck$i.${x##*.}
  mv "$x" truck$i.${x##*.} && i=$((i+1))      
done
```

The `for x in *` operates on all files whose names do not begin with a dot and are in the current directory. You can adjust the glob to be more exclusive, but this script will need modification if the files are in other directories. Again, probably easier to collect the files in one directory, or maybe put it in a script file and execute it in multiple directories using `find ... -exec`.

This uses `i` as a counter to generate the digits. The trick is the `${x##*.}` expression which takes the file name and deletes everything up to the final dot. This allows you to preserve and reattach the file extension to the new name.  **You have to be careful to set `i` correctly** or you will overwrite old `truck1` files with new ones.

Comment: If you want to not increment if the rename fails, you'd have to `&&` the `mv` and the increment.

Comment: Either use `mv ... && ((i++))` as DevSolar mentioned or you could use `mv ... || continue`.